# Error when trying to lookup database

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a button that has code attached to it:

```
DataTable pieteikumu_tabula = new DataTable();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM pieteikums",con);
        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(pieteikumu_tabula);
        con.Close();
        Form2 pieteikumi = new Form2(pieteikumu_tabula);
        pieteikumi.Show();
```

The thing is that whenever I open the program in debug mode, I don't get the error, but when I use ctrl+F5 I do.

Comment: Check your connection string

Comment: "Npgsql.NpgsqlException:
A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup".

Comment: You are getting different behaviours when started in debug mode, from when you select run? Check to see if you've set something specific (such as command line or starting directory) for your debug config (start here, maybe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx )    Also, where is the `con` variable defined and initialised? That could well be where the issue arises, so maybe post that code too?

Comment: Please post complete error(stack trace & error msg) with Error code.

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE it's extremely long. Here's a part of it:Npgsql.NpgsqlException:
A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlClosedState.Open(NpgsqlConnector context) in c:\C#Apps\github.npgsql.Npgsql.stock\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlClosedState.cs:line 232
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open() in c:\C#Apps\github.npgsql.Npgsql.stock\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 677